# Docker-plugin on Jenkins fails to Test Connection

Tags: jenkins, docker

I have ubuntu server with installed docker on it. 
I have deployed Jenkins on Docker with installed docker-plugin on it.

I am trying to add Cloud-docker, with params:

jenkins.version is 1.597

name: docker
Docker Url: 172.17.42.1:4243
connection timeout: 5
read timeout: 15

But I am getting all the time Connection refused error during Test Connection:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused     at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:796)   at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:249)    at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1494)
>     at
>   hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:123)
>     at
>   hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:114)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
>     at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:48)   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
>     at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
>     at
>   hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1474)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:960)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1021)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
>     at
>   winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection
>   refused   at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:184)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:227)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$3.call(JerseyInvocation.java:693)
>     at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)    at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:422)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:689)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:405)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.proxy.WebResourceFactory.invoke(WebResourceFactory.java:318)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy51.version(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.nirima.docker.client.DockerClient$System.version(DockerClient.java:116)
>     at
>   com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerCloud$DescriptorImpl.doTestConnection(DockerCloud.java:341)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:298)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:161)    at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:96)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:121)   at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)  ... 48
>   more Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused     at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
>     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)   at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)  at
>   sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)   at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)   at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)   at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:211)   at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)  at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)  at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:996)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:850)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1300)
>     at
>   java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:276)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:182)
>     ... 70 more

what could be wrong?

thanks

Comment: The answer for Docker for Windows is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59825273/434145

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is solved

listener with opened port 4243 should be opened anyway even if you are running jenkins on the same host where you have docker. I did it. 
But I was running listener as:

```
 sudo docker -H tcp://127.0.0.1:4243 -d &
```

but should be

```
 sudo docker -H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243 -d &
```

and do not forget to add a rule to the firewall.

Comment: A couple things, you shouldn't need sudo to run your docker commands, just make sure to add the user you're running docker from to the docker gorup.

Also, after setting your daemon to 0.0.0.0, you may have trouble running local commands. I recommend this alias. `alias docker='docker -H 127.0.0.1:4243'`

Answer (score 1):

You can update `/etc/default/docker.io` file with the entry below.

```
DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more the solution you provide?

Comment: And in this case I don't need to run the agent anymore?